# Eclipse patch file not working for same project with different name

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, patch

I created an Eclipse patch file by clicking on Team > Create Patch file, and then tried to apply the patch file to the exact same project (meaning it was a checkout of the same project) and Eclipse seemed to recognize the Project as different because it's Project name wasn't the same? I though Eclipse would have used the svn properties, but it looks like maybe the patch option doesn't do this? Is there a way around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse's create patch wizard by default will create a patch for the workspace (including the project's name).  This is useful for patches that span multiple projects but not so useful for your use case.  If you click next on the create patch wizard you will see the option to create the patch per project (see screenshot).

[image]